# Session Timeout issue in Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, session-timeout

we are working on a web application which is developed using Struts 2 Framework. Recently we have moved to Amazon AWS for better service. we are using the Elastic Bean Stalk feature for our  Live,  Staging, Beta applications. On live & Beta instances, we enable the autoscaling feature from Bean stalk, which on excess load increases the instances, during this process, the already existing user logged in is session timed out, as his session is switching between instances. There fore we are facing the session timeout issue frequently. Please suggest me solutions for this issue.

--
Thanks,
Anand S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of two options:

- Enable stickiness on the load balancer so all requests by a single user are routed to the same server.  [Here's](http://shlomoswidler.com/2010/04/elastic-load-balancing-with-sticky-sessions.html) a discussion on that.
- Use a session state server so your session data is not saved on the autoscaled servers

Comment: I have the same issue with my EC2 but I don't use any load balancer. Session stays alive until I refresh the page once I refresh the page my session gets expired. Do you have any idea on this strange behavior? Also, this doesn't occur every time.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to increase the session timeout with this session var:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3660);
```

In addition, enabling stickiness on the load balancer might be required if you have multiple web servers for your beanstalk.